# Post.php - Conditional statements for new post and edit post

Tags: metabox, conditional-tags

This question came up when creating a custom meta box for the edit.php page.

Is there a conditional statement to target posts that are already exist vs posts that are not created yet?

The idea:

```
If editing post (post exists) {
 // Display custom input field
} else if adding post (post does not exist)
 // Hide custom input field
}
```

This snippet would be used in a custom meta box.

I wasn't too sure what to search for, because it seemed to broad...

Would the simplest (and efficient) solution be to check if a post title exist? I haven't tried it yet - but it seems that it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`edit.php` is the post/page **list**, the post creation/editing screen are 2 separate files: `post-new.php` and `post.php`.

so you can target using [`"load-$page"`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) hook, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', function() {
  // add metabox or whatever you want when EDITING post
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_meta_box_editing' );
} );

add_action( 'load-post-new.php', function() {
  // add metabox or whatever you want when creating NEW post
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_meta_box_new' );
} );
```

To get more specific information (e.g. the post type being cretaed/edited) as **@KrzysiekDróżdż** alredy said, you can use the current screen object, however I suggest you to use [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function for the porpose.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', function() {
  // add metabox or whatever you want when EDITING post
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  // this should give you an idea of the infromation you can get
  // DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $screen );
  die();
} );
```

When adding a metabox, as alterantive or in addiction to previous methods, the callback you use for to output the metabox (the 3rd param of [`add_metabox`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function) receive the post id, so using [`get_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) you can retrieve the post object being edited an look at the `post_status` you can know if the post is just created or not:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

function myplugin_add_meta_box() {
  // do you need information about screen?
  // this can be used, e.g. to use different metabox callback if
  // editing or creating a new post
  // $screen = get_current_screen(); 
  add_meta_box(
    'myplugin_sectionid', // metabox id
     __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), // metabox label
     'myplugin_meta_box_callback', // metabox callback, see below
     'post' // this metabox is for 'post' post type
  );
}

function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post_id ) {
   $post = get_post( $post_id );
   $status = $post->post_status;
   if ( $status === 'new' || $status === 'auto-draft' ) {
     // this is a new post
   } else {
     // editing an already saved post
   }
}
```

Comment: `$status` snippet worked wonderfully. I placed it within my metabox. No need to created additional action and function codes. Thanks!

Comment: @Roc yes, it works :) the `"load-$page"` hook is needed when you want performa an action early, e.g. add some css to page.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
global $current_screen;

if ( $current_screen->action == 'add' ) {
    // you're adding new post
} else {
    // you're editing...
}
```

If you want to do this only with one post type, you can check `id` field like this:

```
if ( $current_screen->action == 'page' ) ... // or post, etc.
```

You need to be careful. You shouldn't chceck `$current_screen` before it is set. Any hook after [`current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request) should be OK (so `wp` hook should work like a charm, but in `init` hook this object will be NULL).